# running sbt assembly in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I'm new to scala and sbt and am having trouble running a project in intellij.  This is the sample project I tried to import into intellij.

https://github.com/snowplow/spark-example-project

it works fine if I run the sbt assembly command from command line, but if I try to create an "application" run configuration in intellij I get an error in its dependencies: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool

How can I run and debug the sbt project in intellij?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a challenge to get spark to run in Intellij: and the "answers" on how to do so change based on the spark version and if you were running off of master or not.

The best bet is:

- "Import project" and then navigate to the spark_home directory.
- choose "sbt project"  (or if you prefer "maven project")
- rest of options you should be able to use the defaults.

Caveat: this process is working in master from around the beginning of 2015 - and in the released 1.3.0 branch as of the middle of march 2015.

Previously there would be some involved surgery required to the Intellij project/modules after the import were completed.

Answer (score 0):

The important part is getting your dependencies correct.

I like to create a lib folder and place my spark files there, e.g.

within lib:

```
spark-streaming_2.10-2.1.0.jar

spark-sql_2.10-2.1.0.jar

spark-core_2.10-2.1.0.jar
```

Then my sbt file:

```
name := "Project_Name"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.6"
retrieveManaged := true

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "2.1.0"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.10
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "2.1.0"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming_2.10
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.10" % "2.1.0" % "provided"
```

As you can see, I strongly encourage you to get both the .jar and the string you stick in your sbt file from https://mvnrepository.com

Also, check out the jar file versions. They should be the same (2.10-2.1.0 in my case)